# What is the "=~" operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators

I saw this on a screencast and couldn't figure out what it was. Reference sheets just pile it in with other operators as a general pattern match operator.

Comment: @user97370: Quite often ruby docs are used as a flippant solution to answer all questions without realizing that ruby docs is not always an easy-to-understand site. Quite often (most of the time) I start with ruby docs, fail to understand the encrypted, anemic explanations then Google, only to find there are also no solutions on Google. One does not simply Google "Ruby =~" or "Ruby =~ method" or "Ruby =~ operator" to get an answer. It would be nice to see fewer people throw ruby docs out as a lazy solution and to see more in depth answers that actually help.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It matches string to a regular expression.

`'hello' =~ /^h/ # => 0`

If there is no match, it will return `nil`.  If you pass it invalid arguments (ie, left or right-hand sides are not correct), it will either throw a `TypeError` or return `false`.

Answer (score 20):

From [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core/) :

**`str =~ obj => fixnum or nil`**

Match—If obj is a Regexp, use it as a pattern to match against str, and returns the offset position the match starts, or nil if there is no match. Otherwise, invokes obj.=~, passing str as an argument. The default =~ in Object returns false.

```
"cat o' 9 tails" =~ /\d/   #=> 7
"cat o' 9 tails" =~ 9      #=> false
```

Comment: "returns the position the match starts", is the important bit for me :) Been scouring Google for an answer.. found it here thanks!

Comment: Why does the second example return false? Is it because `9` isn't a string?

Comment: yes, to test for the string "9" you would need to enclose it in forward slashes so it's interpreted like a regex: /9/

Answer (score 5):

Well, the reference is correct, it is the "matches this regex" operator.

```
if var =~ /myregex/ then something end
```

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers already stated, `=~` is the regular expression vs string match operator.

**Note: The `=~` operator is not commutative**

Please consider the note below from the [ruby doc site](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E), as I have seen yet only the first form

```
str =~ regexp
```

used in the other answers:

> Note: `str =~ regexp` is not the same as `regexp =~ str`. Strings captured
>   from named capture groups are assigned to local variables only in the
>   second case.

Here is the documentation for the second form: [link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E)

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression string matching. Here's a detailed list of operators: http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/tut_expressions.html#table_7.1

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression string matching:

puts true if url =~ /google.com/

You can read '=~' as 'is matching'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a pattern matching operator used with regex.