# Using regex in Ruby if condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use regex as the conditional in a Ruby (1.9.2) if statement but it keeps returning true even when the regex evaluates to nil

```
if (params[:test] =~ /foo/)
  return "match"
else
  return "no match"
end
```

The above returns "match" even when `Rails.logger.info(params[:test])` shows test as set to `"bar"`

Comment: I can't reproduce this (and it shouldn't happen). Probably your assumption that `params[:test] == "bar"` is faulty.

Comment: I've just check it in irb command line and I can't reproduce your situation. `"bar" =~ /foo/` returns nil. Your issue is somewhere else...

Comment: I have Rails.logger.info(params[:test]) the line above the if statement and it outputs "bar"

Comment: @Exupery: Try `Rails.logger.info(params[:test].class)`. It just can't be that `params[:text] == "bar"`, otherwise your Ruby is buggy, which seems very unlikely. Can you use pry to peek at the current execution index before the `if`? This will let you debug the current value of `params[:test]` better than a logging statement (and you can try the regex matching interactively).

Comment: .class returns String - sorry for my poor wording in saying it returned true. My assumption was that when params[:test] is "bar" the regex will return nil, which would cause the else clause to run.

Comment: Do this and post what gets written to the console:  `if ((s = params[:test]; p s; s) =~ /foo/...` - I know this *should* match what Rails.logger outputs, but it *might* not.

Comment: @regularfry not able to do that in the console and accurately replicate the setting of the test parameter. However other methods in the same helper are consistently showing params[:test] as "bar"

Comment: Then I'm with Niklas. `params[:test]` is not "bar" in this case.  Or, more likely, if "bar" and /foo/ are stand-ins for more complex values you'd rather not show us, whatever /foo/ *actually* is, matches "bar" in some unexpected way.

Comment: Upon further testing it seems the condition is only getting properly evaluated the first time the method is called. Subsequent calls return  the same value regardless of what "test" becomes. Obviously I'll need to try and determine what's causing Rails to use the cached value. Thanks to everyone for the assistance.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
if params[:test] =~ /foo/
    # Successful match
else
    # Match attempt failed
end
```

Works for me. Debug what is in `params[:test]`

Comment: hi @michael, could you explain what the "=~" does and other uses? This is new to me and just kinda wanted some understanding.

Comment: @RogerPerez See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025838/what-is-the-operator-in-ruby) question Or the [docs link](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-3D-7E+operator) mention there.