# RoR: checking for numeric value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have found a code for checking whether string is numeric. And it works fine. But I am not
getting how is it working. Can anyone explain it.

```
    str = "12132344", str1="abcd", str2="12213234.132332"

    /^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/ === str  #=> true  //perfect
    /^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/ === str1 #=> false //perfect
    /^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/ === str2 #=. true  //perfect
```

when i change the comparison like below:

```
    str === /^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/ #=>  false
    str1 === /^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/ #=> false
    str2 === /^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/ #=> false
```

Also I found alternate way to do this by using match.

Can anyone explain what is (===) operator doing here? How it works? Is there any other alternate way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025838/what-is-the-operator-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, operator overloading can be used to define what each operator does, but it must be done by the class on the left hand side of the operator.

This method is defined in the Ruby Standard Library for the `Regexp` object class. Reference: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D.

It only works with the `Regexp` class (that is the pattern) on the left hand side because it is defined to work that way only in the `Regexp` class.

In this case, `Regexp` defines `===` as a synonym for `=~`, which matches a string given a regular expression pattern.

The `String` class defines the `===` operator as an equality operator. This means it returns false if the right hand argument is not a string, and otherwise returns true only if both strings match. Reference: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D

Comment: Is this feature belongs to only 1.9.2??? I am using ruby enterprise edition 1.8.7 , it is working in that.

Comment: You'll have to check the documentation for 1.8.7, but many things generally stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_numeric?(str)
  str =~ /^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/
end
```