# Ruby: =~ symbol - what does it mean

Tags: ruby

What does =~ in ruby mean?

I tried to get help on codementor.io recently and the change made to this tutorial:

http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

was to replace this line:

```
self.email && self.email !~ TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX
```

with this line:

```
self.email && TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX =~ self.email
```

What does =~ mean?

Comment: First result on google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025838/what-is-the-operator-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks - I've been googling for an hour. Closest I could get was !=

Comment: I find [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%3D%7E) to be better at this sort of thing than Google.