# Explanation needed for this Ruby challenge

Tags: ruby

I need some help understanding this code:

```
def SimpleAdding(num)
  sum = 0
  (num + 1).times do |x|
    sum = sum + x
  end
  return sum
end

SimpleAdding(12) #=> 78
SimpleAdding(140) #=> 9870
```

I am not sure of the method. Why is the method written the way it is? Why is `sum` on the first line set to `0`? And why is `sum = sum + x` used on the third line?

Comment: Would you be willing to paste your code in your question, please?

Comment: I suspect it is actually the `times` method that's causing you problems. Try playing around with it for example what's the output for `4.times{|x| puts x}` etc

Comment: The variable **sum** is given the initial value of `0`, you create a reference to a `Fixnum` object, otherwise it would be impossible to perform an additional operation on it.

Comment: I don't think you can really answer why this code is written the way it is without knowing what it is supposed to accomplish

Comment: bad example to learn Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, the `def` **keyword** delimits the start of a **method**, in your case named `SimpleAdding`. It takes one **argument** (in the parentheses) named `num`.

In the method body, the **variable** `sum` is given the initial value of `0`.

The line containing `(num + 1).times do |x|` tells Ruby to execute the code between the `do` and `end` keywords a set number of times (an **iterator**), in this case `num + 1`. Remember, `num` represents the value received in the form of an argument when the method was called.

On the next line, the variable `sum` (initialized to `0` at the beginning of the method) is *assigned* the value of itself plus `x`.

Next line, our iterator `end`s.

Finally, we `return` the value stored inside of the variable `sum`.

And, the `end` of our method.

Enjoy learning Ruby!

Comment: Thanks for helping Hatchet! Appreciate it!

Comment: @tbunz If you feel it would be helpful to others, you can [mark my answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer (me) and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: One more quick question @hatchet, what does =~ mean in ruby? It just means matches right?

Comment: @tbunz More specifically, it matches a string to a regular expression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025838/what-is-the-operator-in-ruby